# Chef and aws cookbook error

Tags: chef-infra

As soon as I add the [aws cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/aws) to my chef solo deploy I got this error:

```
FATAL: NameError: wrong constant name Aws.ElasticIp
```

Here the stacktrace:

```
NameError: wrong constant name Aws.ElasticIp
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider.rb:89:in `const_defined?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider.rb:89:in `build_from_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:89:in `block in load_lwrp_providers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:120:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in foreach_cookbook_load_segment'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:119:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:119:in `block in foreach_cookbook_load_segment'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:117:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:117:in `foreach_cookbook_load_segment'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:87:in `load_lwrp_providers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/run_context.rb:58:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/client.rb:195:in `setup_run_context'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/client.rb:159:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `block in run_application'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo:19:in `<main>'
```

even if I don't include the `recipe[aws]` on the deploy. Other cookbook like mysql, redis, rvm, database are working ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue removing hidden files (mac os autogenerated file) from the code I was uploading to the server. Tarring the folder with COPYFILE_DISABLE=true let me solve the problem.